# Receive can packets with a specific id

Tags: beagleboneblack, can-bus

is there method to receive packets from `can` only with specific id or match mask? Example: if packet has id 0x123 it has to ignore. 
I want to do it by driver level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure the mailbox to receive the messages from an intended message ID. You can change it in the library or driver of beagleboard